# ls hangs after the machine hosting the source folder is paused

Tags: linux, rhel, mount, ls

I have two instances of RHEL 7 Linux, machine 1 and machine 2. Machine 2 has a folder that is mounted to a remote folder from machine 1. It is done with command: `mount -t cifs -o user=aaa,pass=password //machine 1's ip/SrcFolder/`. This works fine but however when I pause machine 1 then if I issue a command such as `ls` it would hang in machine 2. If I unpause machine 1 then everything is back to normal. I am suspecting that whatever the daemon running mount is holding on to the file system resource which prevents other i/o operation from completing? Is there a way so the daemon can detect unavailable source right away and disconnect?

This is the output from `mount | grep [mount point]`
[image]

Comment: Does the hang occur when you run `ls` within *all* directories on machine 2?

Comment: I run the ls command from the home directory and the mounted folder is also under home directory.

Comment: The ls command hangs doesn't really bother me as much. What bothers me is the snmpwalk or other snmp related quest to machine 2 will also hang because of unavailable mounted folder.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `mount | grep [mount-point]` from machine 2?